# When should we re-certify Outlook Add-in after initial AppSource publish

Tags: office-store

We already have a HTML/JS based Outlook Add-In published via AppSource. I would like to know if we have have to initiate a new publishing request if the HTML/JS has been updated on the hosting server. Is a new publishing request required for the add-in to be updated on desktop Outlook clients.

Points to be noted:

- there are no manifest file changes.
- changes only html & js changes on the hosting server.
- no change to user experience since the first Outlook Add-In certification.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is recommended to resubmit the offer to ensure policy compliance.